# Recursion code it not working properly what can be the issue here?

Tags: c

Tried a program which prints the first 50 natural number I wrote this code which returns the value using recursion but its not printing anything not returning any values what m I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int naturalNumbers(int i)
{
    if (i == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        naturalNumbers(i--);
        return i;
    }
}
                
int main()
{
    printf("%d", naturalNumbers(50));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The expression naturlaNumbers(i--) calls natural numbers with the value of i and will then reduce the value of i by one. Therefore you are calling naturalNumbers(50) in an endless loop. You can try naturalNumbers(--i)

Comment: After making `i--` to  `i - 1`, the function only returns one 1 value, its input. All the recursive work is essentially thrown out. What are you expecting this to print? Maybe you intended to return a list or print inside the recursive function?

Comment: I assume you're trying to print all natural numbers between you're initial argument and 1. To do this, you should call `printf` inside your recursive function. Otherwise, your function called from main will always return one value.

Comment: Thanks guys it worked I used the print function and it worked

Answer (score 2):

below recursion will print numbers in increasing order

```
void naturalNumbers(int i)
{
    if(i<1) return; //base case
    naturalNumbers(i-1);
    printf("%d ", i);
}

naturalNumbers(50); // call from main function
```

Comment: answer is updated

Comment: You better not use `vector` for the question is tagged as `C`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating an endless loop, you should modify your `naturalNumbers` function as follows:

```
int naturalNumbers(int i)
{
    if (i == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        naturalNumbers(--i);
        return i;
    }
}
```

This will decrement the value of `i` **before** calling naturalNumbers instead of **afterwards** as in your version. However, the return value of this original call will always be `(i-1)`. Can you please explain a little bit more about the intent of this function?

Comment: The natural numbers are : 1  2  3
  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13
  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  
22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  
39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47
  48  49  50

Comment: this is what I want as a output

Comment: Then you need to add a print call to each recursive iteration and you can remove the return value as shown by @arbitrary_A

Comment: thanks it worked